# Is there a financial product similar to an annuity in Germany?

Tags: germany, annuity

I'm trying to figure out how to buy an [annuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annuity_(European)) in Germany. Specifically, I'm interested in a fixed immediate life annuity. That is, a product that would offer a fixed payout every month for the lifetime of the owner.

In the US, these products are offered by many financial companies including life insurance companies and investment companies, but I'm not sure what to search for as an equivalent product in Germany.

When I switch languages on Wikipedia from English [Annuity(European)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annuity_(European)) to the German equivalent page, I land on a list of pages related to [retirement](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rente). [Life Annuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_annuity) is linked to [Leibrente](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibrente) but this product seems to be tied to real estate, more similar to a reverse mortgage. There is also a false-friend [Annuität](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annuit%C3%A4t_(Investitionsrechnung)), which if defined on Wikipedia like Annuity but when I search google, returns results about paying back credits.

Frustrating the search process further, the standard retirement plan in Germany is an annuity, which means that google mostly returns results about the government supported retirement. I want to know how to buy a private additional annuity on top of standard "Rente".

German is my second language, so please jump in and clarify any misunderstandings I may have included in the body of the question due to misreading the Wikipedia pages.

Comment: Have you tried contacting German insurance companies?  Or anyone else who sells annuities  such as brokerage firms?

Comment: It's possible that they are simply 'not a thing' in the German market. Certainly the UK equivalent ("purchased life annuity") is rare.

Comment: @AakashM It is a thing in Germany. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The financial product you are looking for is called *Sofortrente* ("Immediate retirement"). You pay a large amount of money once, and from then on receive monthly smaller payments for the rest of your life. The ratio of payment to repayments usually depends on your remaining life expectancy, calculated from your age and health status.

This product is offered by most life insurance companies which also offer regular private retirement plans.